# Extract substrings between strings

Tags: sed, grep, unix-text-processing

I have a file with text as follows:

```
###interest1 moreinterest1### sometext ###interest2###
not-interesting-line
sometext ###interest3###
sometext ###interest4### sometext othertext ###interest5### sometext ###interest6###
```

I want to extract all strings between `###` .

My desired output would be something like this:

```
interest1 moreinterest1
interest2
interest3
interest4
interest5
interest6
```

I have tried the following:

```
grep '###' file.txt | sed -e 's/.*###\(.*\)###.*/\1/g'
```

This almost works but only seems to grab the first instance per line, so the first line in my output only grabs

```
interest1 moreinterest1
```

rather than

```
interest1 moreinterest1
interest2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a single `awk` command to achieve this that makes `###` field separator and prints each even numbered field:

```sh
awk -F '###' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $i}' file

interest1 moreinterest1
interest2
interest3
interest4
interest5
interest6
```

Here is an *alternative* `grep + sed` solution:

```sh
grep -oE '###[^#]*###' file | sed -E 's/^###|###$//g'
```

This assumes there are no `#` characters in between `###` markers.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, I made some edits to my example. Your solution almost works, but some of my stings between the `###` have spaces in them, which your solutions don't seem to accommodate. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The awk solution works, thanks! In my real file, I have some other text within regions of interest besides space characters, so that may be the reason why the grep/sed solution still isn't quite what I want. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Indeed `awk` is more robust solution that `grep + sed`. I will move it up.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='###' '!(NR%2)' file
interest1 moreinterest1
interest2
interest3
interest4
interest5
interest6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pcregrep`:

```sh
pcregrep -o1 '###(.*?)###' file
```

The regex - `###(.*?)###` - matches `###`, then captures into Group 1 any zero o more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and `###` then matches `###`.

`o1` option will output Group 1 value only.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/geCepR/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 't x
s/###/\
/;D; :x
s//\
/;t y
D;:y
P;D' file
```

Replacing "###" with newline, `D`, then conditionally branching to `P` if a second replacement of "###" is successful.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU  sed):

```
sed -n 's/###/\n/g;/[^\n]*\n/{s///;P;D}' file
```

Replace all occurrences of `###`'s by newlines.

If a line contains a newline, remove any characters before and including the first newline, print the details up to and including the following newline, delete those details and repeat.